# Why isn't the :coffee filter working in my Sinatra + haml project?

Tags: ruby, coffeescript, sinatra, haml

I'm at a loss as to why this isn't working.

Here's my little piece of template:

```
%script
  :coffee
    # underscore.string setup
    window._s = window.s
    delete window.s
```

Here's Sinatra's reaction:

[image: Screenshot]

Okay, I'm using HAML templates. The docs here say that the `:coffee` filter is implemented using `tilt`:

> http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html

Cool. Now, Tilt's docs says that rendering coffee script requires the `coffee-script` library:

> https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt

I apparently have everything I need installed:

```
$ gem list | egrep "tilt|coffee|haml"
coffee-script (2.4.1)
coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
haml (4.0.7)
tilt (2.0.1)
```

So why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this had a simple explanation in the end, and I figured it out right before posting the question.

Short story, I had to:

```
require "coffee_script"
```

Longer story, I had already tried importing it but got import errors, so I assumed Tilt would handle that for me. The reason I got import errors was that I hadn't added `coffee_script` to my Gemfile. I really didn't think that mattered, but apparently it does in Sinatra applications, as well as in `pry`.

Hoping this question won't get down voted too hard, and that it helps somebody else with similar problems.